# Emacs. How to delete until and including bracket?

Tags: emacs

I used to use M-d to delete long sub strings in lines like:

```
if ( aaaaa[dddd(d,s,d)] + bbbbbb[ssd] ) {
```

but it always annoying me that i need to delete the last bracket. For example to delete first term `aaaaa[dddd(d,s,d)]` i need to press M-d 4 times and C-d 2 times.

I wonder, is there a command which will delete every-thing until a closing bracket, which corresponds to first opening bracket?

So it should delete whole `dddd(d,s,d)` if your cursor stays at `d`, whole `aaaaa[dddd(d,s,d)]` if you start from `a` and whole `if ( aaaaa[dddd(d,s,d)] + bbbbbb[ssd] )` if you start at the beginning of the line.

In principle set of commands `M-d C-space M-C-f C-w` will do the job, but I looking for one standard solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try either `M-C-k` (`kill-sexp`), or `M-z ]` (`zap-to-char`).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331725/how-to-kill-a-quoted-string-at-point-in-emacs)
to do the task that you describe.

It's basically a generalized `kill-sexp` - it will kill
any list with the point inside it. Also works for strings.

Answer (score 0):

`smartparens-mode` (https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens or MELPA) knows how to deal with expressions enclosed in various types of parentheses/brackets/etc. It's behavior is often language-specific. For instance, if you bind

```lisp
(define-key sp-keymap (kbd "C-M-k") 'sp-kill-sexp)
```

then if you are on the first`(` in your expression, <kbd>C-M-k</kbd> will kill everything including the final `)`. Or see this [c++ example](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens/wiki/Working-with-expressions#decorators). I realize this is not the exact behavior you described but the package has many (mode-specific) tweaks configuration options.

As an alternative, the regular `zap-up-to-char` and `zap-to-char` accept numerical argument. I bound `zap-up-to-char` to <kbd>M-z</kbd>, so, say <kbd>C-u 2 M-z )</kbd> kills everything up to final `)`.

Answer (score 0):

I use these methods:

```lisp
(defun zdo/zap-up-to-pair-and-delete-pair ()
  (interactive)
  (call-interactively 'zap-up-to-char)
  (let
      ((delete-pair-blink-delay 0))
    (delete-pair))
  )
(defun zdo/zap-up-to-pair-and-delete-pair-round ()
  (interactive)
  (zap-up-to-char 1 ?\()
  (let
      ((delete-pair-blink-delay 0))
    (delete-pair))
  )
```

In case (`|` is cursor location)

```
WHERE foo = ${|escape(bar)}
```

the second method makes it

```
WHERE foo = ${|bar}
```